# There was an error deleting your app. Please try again later. (iTunesConnect)

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I want To delete an application on iTunesConnect but I still get an error message even after 48 hours :

[image: Error Message when deleting]

I checked :

- iAd is not enabled for my App
- My app is not part of Game Center

I have two versions :

- 2.1 : Developer Removed From Sale
- 3.0 : Prepare for Submission

[image: Status]

I followed the steps on the official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html), but I still can't delete the App

I've been looking for a solution for a week now, plz help :)
If anyone have an idea, I'll be very grateful.

Regards

Comment: If you are *certain* that you have followed the instructions to delete an app then you have a problem that only Apple can solve. So my suggestion is to call/email Apple.

Comment: Thanks Robotic Cat, for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple answered me after more than 20 days!
It was their problem, here's the message :

[image]